# SQL remove leading hyphens (-) from DB and remove consecutive whitespaces

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

In one of my fields, I have data that looks like

```
-  Data with spaces, some other data,   .
```

I put the . at the end so you can see that it has double whitespace

I want to remove the - and remove any and all double (or more spaces). Leaving the result with a single white space.

Not all data in the column has a leading hyphen ( - )
Some of them are

```
Data with spaces, some other data
Data  with  double  spaces,  some other data  . (double space at end)
  Data with leading double space, some other data
- Some data with hyphen,  and double space
  - double space leading hyphen, some other data
```

These are the few variations in the DB. I was attempting to fix each one manually but it takes so long to correct an entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
rtrim(ltrim(REPLACE (COLUMN_NAME, '-', ' ')))
```

I did not understand if you need an extra space in the end, but if you do just add +' '

Answer (score 1):

You can try to combine some of the [core functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) to get the result you want.

For example, the query

```
select trim(substr('-  Data with spaces, some other data,   ', 2))
```

outputs `Data with spaces, some other data,`

First I removed  the `-` by returning a substring, then I trimmed the whitespace.

Edit: checking out for leading `-` character

```
select trim(
   case
      when (substr(FIELD, 1, 1) in ('-'))
         then substr(FIELD, 2)
      else
         FIELD
   end)
```

The `in ('-')` is for the case you want to exclude more symbols, ex.
 `in ('-', '+', ',')`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work. It is kind of messy though, so I am not sure if this is what you want or not. you may want a recursive function like a cte to remove more than 2 spaces though. But, this solves the problem as presented.

```
select 
case SUBSTRING('-  Data with spaces, some other data,   .', 1,1)
    when '-' then REPLACE(
        SUBSTRING('-  Data with spaces, some other data,   .',2,
            LEN('-  Data with spaces, some other data,   .')-1)
        ,'  ',' ')
    else REPLACE('-  Data with spaces, some other data,   .','  ',' ')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

we can use update query with replace function

```
update info_table
set address = replace(address, ' ', '-')
```

out-put 
[image]

i have taken this details on [neerajcodesolutions.com](http://%20https://www.neerajcodesolutions.com/2018/01/how-to-remove-space-with-dash-in-sql-server.html)